# select an option of a dropbox with find()

Tags: jquery, dom

I find an object (select) with this code :

```
var pays_fact = $("#form_facturation").find('#ld_pays');
```

I would like to know if it is possible to select an option of this object ?

I tried this :

```
pays_fact.attr('option:eq(12)').prop('selected', true);  // To select via value
```

No success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since your `select` has an ID, no need to `find` it, just target it (since your ID's *must* be unique). You can set the option like so:

```
$("#ld_pays option:eq(12)").prop("selected", true);
```

Edit: since you have multiple ID's... (still not good)

```
var pays_fact = $("#form_facturation").find('#ld_pays');
$("option:eq(12)", pays_fact).prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: I'm ok with you, unfortunately, I have two selects with same id.  I know it's bad, but it's like that.

Comment: I want to accept the reply yesterday, but I had to wait 7 minutes, I did today. Again, thank you for your reply.  Where can I find information about your reply please ?